# ngnix logging datetime doesn't match system time

Tags: raspbian, timekeeping

`date` command prints correct datetime according to my timezone.
but ngnix logging with different datetime.

this makes me wonder if there are independent multiple source for datetime in unix?

how can I fix it? because my flask application is also picking up wrong time. I am scheduling crone like jobs in my flask app.

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date
Fri  7 Oct 00:32:14 IST 2016
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail /var/log/nginx/access.log 
192.168.0.104 - - [06/Oct/2016:18:50:13 +0000] "GET /wake/0:21 HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.0.104 - - [06/Oct/2016:18:50:48 +0000] "GET /wake/0:21 HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.0.104 - - [06/Oct/2016:19:03:07 +0000] "GET /wake/0:33 HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"`

Comment: `date` lists IST, the log shows "+0000", so UTC. That should account for 5:30h difference as is. Though I do not know why, [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/) suggests that nginx' access log uses local time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do edit **/etc/init.d/nginx** and add

```
export TZ="Europe/Berlin"
```

at the begining of the file. Check the php manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for valid timezone. So you would have something like

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nginx
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO
export TZ="Europe/Berlin"
...
```

If the OS you are using doesn't use init scripts, then try restarting whatever syslog service you are using and/or doing a systemwide timezone setting i.e. use tzselect and follow the instructions/prompts.